# Following namespaces in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

Given this data structure

```
@prefix core <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
<http://localhost/myvocab/1> core#notation 1 .
<http://localhost/myvocab/1> <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inDateTime> <http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> .

<http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#year>  2016 ;
            <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#month>  "June"
```

If I run

```
select * where {?s ?p ?o . 
                    <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#notation> 1 . }
```

then only the first 2 triples (`:hasID` and `:hasTime`) are returned. Is there a sparql query (preferably not using a regex filter for matching the id) to return all triples from the child namespaces too?

I'm *hoping* I can achieve a result something along the lines of

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| s                                                | p                                              | o                                               |
=======================================================================================================================================================
| <http://localhost/myvocab/item1>                 | <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inDateTime>       | <http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription |
| <http://localhost/myvocab/item1>                 | <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#notation> | 1                                               |
| <http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> | <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#month>            | "June"                                          |
| <http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> | <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#year>             | 2016                                            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What do you mean by "child namespaces"?  You mean that you want to follow the properties to get year 2016 and month June as well?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yeh. (So, what's the correct generic term for those?)

Comment: The `<.../item1#DateTime>` is just another resource.  You're trying to get the properties/values from that resource as well (and perhaps recursively to keep following these).  I don't think there's a specific term for that,but in SPARQL you can use a *property path* to help retrieve it.  You *might* be interested in the term [concise bounded description](https://www.w3.org/Submission/CBD/), which is relevant, though not exactly what you're asking for here, since `<.../item#DateTime>` isn't a blank node.

Comment: You've still got a raw `#notation` in that data.  I'm not even sure that's legal. Even if it is, what is the fragment resolved against?

Comment: But even so, I think that the solution I posted should work on this.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Sorry - that was a typo; fixed now.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've edited the question to show what I'm trying to return...  I hope it makes a bit more sense!

Comment: @ChrisW Just as a side note, there is a typo in your query: you have to use a semicolon instead of a dot. But just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always helps if you provide data that we can actually load and property formed queries that you've tried.  The data that you've shown isn't actually legal, nor is the query that you provided.  Here's some sample data that's actually loadable:

```
@prefix core: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 

<http://localhost/myvocab/1> core:notation 1 ;
                             <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inDateTime> <http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> .

<http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#year> 2016 ;
                                                 <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#month>  "June"
```

If I understand you, you want to follow the :item1_DateTime object's properties too.  You can do that with a property path that follows :item1's properties and value, and so on.  In this query, I use **(:|!:)** as a wildcard, since every property is either **:** or it isn't.  The ***** at the end means to follow paths of arbitrary length.

```sql
prefix core: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

select ?s ?p ?o where {
  ?s_ core:notation 1 ;
      (<>|!<>)* ?s .
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| s                                                | p                                        | o                                                |
==================================================================================================================================================
| <http://localhost/myvocab/1>                     | <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inDateTime> | <http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> |
| <http://localhost/myvocab/1>                     | core:notation                            | 1                                                |
| <http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> | <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#month>      | "June"                                           |
| <http://localhost/myvocab/item1#DateDescription> | <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#year>       | 2016                                             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: First thing to clarify: is `:item1#DateTime` not a legal resource?

Comment: An IRI can certainly end in a fragment like that, but I don't think you can use the # in a turtle style abbreviated IRI like `:item#fragment`.

Comment: Ah, ok - thanks. I guess that's linked to why you've replaced it with `_` - but I'm still struggling with how to follow the hash URLs I'm faced with

Comment: I've updated the question to make the data and query legal

Comment: I get an error `Line 3, column 7: Unresolved prefixed name: :` - I think I was confusing myself before by using a `:` as a prefix when it actually shouldn't have been

Comment: @ChrisW The update didn't make the data legal, there was still a `core#notation` that should have been `core:notation`.  Anyhow, I've updated my answer, and I think it does what you're asking for.

Comment: I'm a little confused - https://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.html#notation implies that using a `#` is legal for skos elements (hence why I left it in there!) - is that a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: but the answer works! Thanks for teaching me about property path querying

Comment: The # can appear in IRIs, but you've already got our in the prefix. Core:name expands as `[whatever core stands for]name`.